# How to extract per shots measurement result from ionq device using qiskit_braket_provider?

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience, amazon-braket, ionq

I'm running a circuit on `ionq device` using `qiskit_braket_provider`. I want to extract per shot measurement results. While running on `IBMQ backends`, it can be accessed by setting `memory=True` in execute function and then running `job.result().get_memory(qc)`. I'm trying to similar thing for `ionq device`, but getting the following error.

**Code:**

```
job = ionq.run(tqc,shots=1024,memory=True)
job.status()
job.wait_for_final_state()
result = job.result()
m = job.result().get_memory(tqc)
print(m)
```

**Error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
QiskitError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [70], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 m = job.result().get_memory(tqc)
      2 m

File ~/anaconda3/envs/qlab/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/result/result.py:217, in Result.get_memory(self, experiment)
    191 def get_memory(self, experiment=None):
    192     """Get the sequence of memory states (readouts) for each shot
    193     The data from the experiment is a list of format
    194     ['00000', '01000', '10100', '10100', '11101', '11100', '00101', ..., '01010']
   (...)
    215         QiskitError: if there is no memory data for the circuit.
    216     """
--> 217     exp_result = self._get_experiment(experiment)
    218     try:
    219         try:  # header is not available

File ~/anaconda3/envs/qlab/lib/python3.10/site-packages/qiskit/result/result.py:380, in Result._get_experiment(self, key)
    373 exp = [
    374     result
    375     for result in self.results
    376     if getattr(getattr(result, "header", None), "name", "") == key
    377 ]
    379 if len(exp) == 0:
--> 380     raise QiskitError('Data for experiment "%s" could not be found.' % key)
    381 if len(exp) == 1:
    382     exp = exp[0]

QiskitError: 'Data for experiment "circuit-7034" could not be found.'
```

***One more thing***, how to extract execution time for job on `ionq device`? In `IBMQ` simply `job.result().time_taken` returns it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell, this information isn't available from the provider because the `header` parameter [isn't supplied](https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-braket-provider/blob/main/qiskit_braket_provider/providers/braket_job.py#L52-L57) to the `ExperimentResult` constructor. This might be worth submitting an [issue](https://github.com/qiskit-community/qiskit-braket-provider/issues) or PR for!

In the meantime, you can get per-shot results by getting the Amazon Braket task result directly:

```
from braket.aws import AwsQuantumTask
task = AwsQuantumTask(job.job_id())
measurements = task.result().measurements
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It worked.